# Openfire xml debugger plugin

Tags: xmpp, openfire

I'm using openfire v4.1.1 and xmldebugger plugin v1.6.0 for my server side. The plugin will print raw XML as it was received and sent by the server as well as interpreted XML (i.e. parsed XML). By default the plugin will only print raw XML.

My problem is, the XML debugger plugin prints only raw XML traffic to stdout even thought the debugger plugin is configured with `plugin.debugger.interpretedAllowed - true` to print XML packets after they were parsed by the server. Don't know what I've missed. Added screen shot for reference.
[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> XML debugger plugin prints only raw XML traffic to stdout.

This issue has been fixed In latest [debugger plugin v1.7.0](https://www.igniterealtime.org/projects/openfire/plugins.jsp). The source code for the plugin can be obtained from git [Openfire](http://github.com/igniterealtime/Openfire) master branch. Check the source for code changes. The following are the fixes they made.

> 1. Debugger plugin will not print encrypted or compressed data.
> 2. Debugger plugin will display remote address.

Don't try the plugin source from any latest openfire source because the xml debugger plugin source has not be updated to latest v1.7.0.